# Is there a free Helvetica Neue Extended alternative?

Tags: website-design, web-fonts, resource-recommendations

Does anybody know a free web font which is a good alternative to the Helvetica Neue Extended? We need it for the headlines on a new website.

Answer (score 2):

There's free for personal use typeface that is really well made and complete. It's my go to typeface for design when I want to use an "Helvetica" type font.

It's called [Neue Montreal](https://pangrampangram.com/products/neue-montreal).

Answer (score 1):

One possible candidate is [Poppins](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins) via Google Fonts.

Comment: Poppins is nothing like Helvetica, sorry. I mean they're both sans, but their design is enormously different.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good alternative. Granted, it isn't identical to the best font ever devised by mankind, (surprise, it's free) but a cursory glance would fool most casual observers. If Jana needs something closer, perhaps they should consider dropping some coin on the genuine article.

Comment: This is probably something the OP can decide, obviously there are differences, but overall and depending on the intended scope, this could be considered about 85% close to HNE. The differences can only be spotted by somebody who knows about fonts, a 'normal' client will most likely not see an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of helvetica-like open source fonts, but few that have extended versions. I managed to find ONE with an extended version:

[Lunchtype](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lunchtype)
[image]

Helvetica Neue Extended for reference
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the closest free alternative is TeX Gyre Heros:

[image: TeX Gyre Heros vs. Helvetica]

Warning: it only comes in two weights.

For a more fully-featured open source alternative, try Inter:

[image: Inter vs. Helvetica]

These are 2 of the [7 best Helvetica alternatives](https://learnui.design/blog/helvetica-similar-fonts.html), IMO. The link includes other suggestions, analysis of options, and download links.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Open Font Lunchtype, very close option

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lunchtype